# How to mark an item as Unread in Safari Reading List?

Tags: macos, safari, reading-list

Sometimes I want to keep an item in the Unread section of the Safari 5.1.3 Reading List after I have read the item. The All section is too cluttered to use as a place to quickly find items. I realize I am trying to use the RL beyond what it was intended to be used for. Nonetheless, is there a way to mark an item in the Safari RL?

Comment: One (lame) possibility which springs to mind is to simply add the page to the Reading List again...

Comment: @djacobson: only way ATM. Not too lame, as you can use the “Read” tab to open the page, then re-add it straightaway … that should be your answer, methinks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've suggested, the Reading List has fairly limited functionality. While you can't mark a page unread directly from the All list, a simple solution is to open the page and add it to the Reading List again.